# tiny mce can't send word tags in ajax

Tags: ajax, tags, tinymce, cpu-word

I'm using tiny mce to send ajax information via the post method. It works OK when I send regular text or even HTML tags; but, when my users paste from a Word document, only the first tag is posted to the server page. I've tried all these addons:

```
          theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
          theme_advanced_resizing: true,
          force_br_newlines: true,
          force_p_newlines: false,
          apply_source_formatting : false,
```

When I see the html code it looks OK, but I always only get the first tag in the server page (something like `<p>`). I've tried everything I can think, and I don't know if it's an ajax or a tiny mce problem.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will have to define those word tags and/or attributes as valid.
Have a closer look at the tinymce confgiuration options valid_elements and valid_children.